# Input values in matrix using conditional statements resulting in errors

Tags: python, matrix

I'm trying to input data into a matrix based on some conditional statements. Nothing of what I've tried is working, here's some code:

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Thomas/ML/p39_time_series.csv")
df_array = dataframe.values

x_dates = df_array[:,4:5] # contains dates
y_sales = df_array[:,1]
list(zip(x_dates, y_sales)) [0:15]
```

output for this:

```
[(array([2007.]), 0.0),
 (array([2007.01923077]), 0.0),
 (array([2007.03846154]), 0.0),
 (array([2007.05769231]), 0.0),
 (array([2007.07692308]), 0.0),
 (array([2007.09615385]), 0.0),
 (array([2007.11538462]), 0.0),
 (array([2007.13461538]), 0.0),
 (array([2007.15384615]), 311.0),
 (array([2007.17307692]), 3664.0),
 (array([2007.19230769]), 7942.0),
 (array([2007.21153846]), 186.0),
 (array([2007.23076923]), 10830.0),
 (array([2007.25]), 8589.0),
 (array([2007.26923077]), 7844.0)]
```

Each "x_dates" element is seperated  by 19 days. So one year we have the date `2007.01923077` and next year we have the output `2008.01923077` which equals the same time of the year, but next year. I want to see the unique timeframes for each year, so for instance, I wanna see the sales every year for the last 10 years from day 19 on. For this I made following code:

```
    minusNumber = 2007

for x in range(x_dates.size):
    print(x_dates[x] - minusNumber)
    if x_dates[x] - minusNumber >= 1.0:
        minusNumber +=1
        x_dates[x] = x_dates[x] - minusNumber

    else:
        x_dates[x] = x_dates[x] - minusNumber



print(x_dates)
```

A sample output:

```
[0.]
[0.01923077]
[0.03846154]
[0.05769231]
[0.07692308]
[0.09615385]
[0.11538462]
[0.13461538]
[0.15384615]
[0.17307692]
[0.19230769] # (....)
```

So since the data is split into weekly data I have 52 unique elements. I have sales data for 10 years. I want a matrix of 52 rows and 10 columns to input all 520 datapoints:

```
uniqueX = numpy.unique(x_dates)
sales, week = 10, 52;
Matrix = [[0 for x in range(sales)] for y in range(week)]
```

Here's the code that doesn't work:

```
for x in x_dates:

    for i in uniqueX:
        if x_dates.item(x) == uniqueX[i]:

            #sales = 10.
            for q in range(sales):
                if Matrix[i][q] != 0:
                    Matrix[i][q] = y_sales[x] #Equal same temperature at the current index.
```

This results in **TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index**

I also tried `if x_dates[x] == uniqueX[i]:` this results in **IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type**

Also tried this

```
if x_dates.item(1) == uniqueX[1]:
```

this results in **TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not numpy.float64**

Comment: `i` takes value for the individual entities of the list  when used in `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted to do this way:

```
for x in range (x_dates.size):

for i in range (uniqueX.size):
    if x_dates.item(x) == uniqueX[i]:

        #sales = 10.
        for q in range(sales):
            if Matrix[i][q] != 0:
                Matrix[i][q] = y_sales[x]
```